# Complete messages using id in Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

We have an application which uses the Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus package today which we want to migrate to using the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package instead.

The application receives messages from topic subscriptions and manually completes or abandons  these messages using the IReceiverClient.CompleteAsync(lockToken).

Is this behavior available in the Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus package or are we forced to complete / abandon messages using the ServiceBusReceivedMessage?

Comment: You may wish to peruse the comments in [#24380](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/24380#issuecomment-934767422) for a work-around if adapting your application to the new pattern isn't feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest SDK requires `ServiceBusReceivedMessage` to be used to complete or abandon a received message. There was a [design discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10852) with the Azure SDK team, whether to expose an overload that takes lock tokens or not. In the end, the Azure SDK team has [decided](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/10852#issuecomment-767781064) not to expose those overloads.

Comment: How about completing a message in an isolated worker process? Where the ServiceBusReceivedMessage isn't available.

Comment: @Wouter, you asked a different question from the OP's question and answered it yourself  Isolated Worker doesn't support message dispositioning as of today. The team is working on bringing feature parity.

Comment: I asked  about a the special case (isolated process ). Which to me is what the OP asked for how to complete it using the ID only. So how to complete it? Always waiting for solutions that just could have been easily made available…. I wish I knew before migrating to isolated proces (which i have to because of the DLL conflicts)

Comment: OP asked about using `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`. That's not the isolated SDK but In-Process SDK. Regardless, you cannot displace the received by function messages, @Wouter. Isolated Worker SDK doesn't support it at this time. Once the SDK adds support for SDK types, ASB would be potentially unblocked. **Potentially**. Here are two issues to track https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/1081 and https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-worker/issues/226. Cheers!

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As for me all is just azure service bus. Shouldn’t make it more difficult by introducing all these different “sub stacks” to get a single thing done.